# Control statements if-else in SAP UI5 XML View

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a technical UI5 doubt.

In XML View how do we use control statements? For example like if-else. I have a condition where if it is satisifed some different lines of code should be rendered. I have looked up and I could find preprocessor instruction:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/40826922922346f890185c8ff02d30da/1.17/en-US/fc185952184c48618ef46306a1517f8c.html

Code:

```
<template:if test="{meta>ImageUrl}">
  <template:then>
    <Image src="{path: 'meta>ImageUrl', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}" />
  </template:then>
  <template:else>
    <Text text="{path: 'meta>Title/Value', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}" />
  </template:else>
</template:if>
```

However, the namespace for "template" (xmlns:template="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.template/1") does not exist anymore.

Does anyone know how to get this working? I do not want to use ternary operator, that's not feasible for the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the visible property. Then the controls will be rendered but not displayed.
The formatter makes the condition whether *undefined* or *null* easier to read.

XML:

```
<Image visible="{ path: 'meta>ImageUrl', formatter: '.Formatter.visible' }" src="{path: 'meta>ImageUrl', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}" />
<Text visible="{ path: 'meta>ImageUrl', formatter: '.Formatter.visible' }" text="{path: 'meta>Title/Value', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}" />
```

Formatter:

```
visible : function(value) {
  return !(typeof(value) === 'undefined' || value === null);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but visibility alone is not what I am looking for. I am concerned that a simple Control statement is not supported in SAP UI5 out of the box which we can do so easily in JSP for example!